Doggy C# random method function errors
I'm learning c#. I came up with the idea of making 'echo' functions for practice. I decided to make a program about dogs and having the console say things about the dog's actions and attributes. The problem is the random function to have the dogs do something at random I keep running into errors.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Breed { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Mood { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }

    public Dog(string name, string breed, string size, string mood, string color)
    {
        Name = name;
        Breed = breed;
        Size = size;
        Mood = mood;
        Color = color;
    }

    public void Walk(string place = null)
    {
        if (place != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is walking to the {place}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is walking somewhere.");
        }
    }

    public void Bark(string emotion = null)
    {
        if (emotion != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is barking {emotion}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is barking.");
        }
    }

    public void Sleep(string timeOfDay = null)
    {
        if (timeOfDay != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is sleeping {timeOfDay}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is sleeping.");
        }
    }

    public void Eat(string food = null)
    {
        if (food != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is eating {food}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is eating.");
        }
    }

    public void Play(string toy = null)
    {
        if (toy != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is playing with the {toy}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is playing.");
        }
    }

    public void Fetch(string item = null)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is fetching the {item}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is fetching something.");
        }
    }

    public void Dig(string place = null)
    {
        if (place != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is digging in the {place}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is digging.");
        }
    }

    public void Swim(string place = null)
    {
        if (place != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is swimming in the {place}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is swimming.");
        }
    }

    public void RollOver()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is rolling over.");
    }

    public void Chase(string target = null)
    {
        if (target != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is chasing the {target}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is chasing something.");
        }
    }

    public void Sniff(string obj = null)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is sniffing the {obj}.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is sniffing.");
        }
    }

    public void WagTail()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} the {Breed} is wagging its tail.");
    }

    public void Describe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Name} is a {Size}, {Color} {Breed} and is currently {Mood}.");
    }

    public void RandomActions()
    {
        var actions = new List<Action> { Walk, Bark, Sleep, Eat, Play, Fetch, Dig, Swim, RollOver, Chase, Sniff, WagTail };
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            int index = random.Next(actions.Count);
            actionsindex;
            actions.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dog dog1 = new Dog("Debbie", "Labrador", "large", "happy", "golden");
        dog1.Describe();
        dog1.RandomActions();

        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Butch", "Pitbull", "stout", "angry", "grey");
        dog2.Describe();
        dog2.RandomActions();
    }
}


Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1950  The best overloaded Add method 'List<Action>.Add(Action)' for the collection initializer has some invalid arguments doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Action'   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  158 
Error (active)  CS0103  The name 'actionsindex' does not exist in the current context   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  163 
Error (active)  CS0201  Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement   doggy   D:\Users\Manny\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Program.cs  163 


My expectation was for the console to show sentences describing the dogs followed by three randomly selected methods being selected describing the dogs doing actions in sentences in the console.

Please read about minimal reproducible examples.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes Wouldn't using lambda with List<Action> avoid unnecesary parameters and keep it clean?

Depends on specific details and your definition of "clean", @hakim00

@Fildor Fair enough. I'm still learning. Just wanted to share my perspective.

E.g. public void Walk(string place = null) is compatible to an Action<string> but you have a List<Action>.
You basically have two options:

Use a List<Action<string>> and add a string parameter to all methods (even if not used in some cases or add something like public void RollOver(string how = null) with how = slowly, fast, happily, etc.).
Add a lambda expression to the collection to make the action match. E.g. to an List<Action> you could add a () => Swim("pool"). This also gives you the opportunity to pass an argument. How would you choose an appropriate string when calling an action randomly otherwise?

var actions = new List<Action> {
    () => Walk(),
    () => Bark("angrily"),
    () => Sleep(),
    () => Eat("a sausage"),
    () => Play(),
    () => Fetch(),
    () => Dig("sand"),
    () => Swim("pool"),
    () => Swim("lake"),
    RollOver,
    () => Chase("rabbit"),
    () => Sniff(),
    WagTail
};

The parameter-less methods can be passed directly.

If you are not familiar with lambda expression yet, here is a short explanation: A lambda expression is a very concise syntax for defining a delegate (like Action or Action<string> or Func<int,bool>) in-line, right where you need it.
E.g. () => Dig("sand") is equivalent to the method declaration:
void AnonymousMethod()
{
    Dig("sand");
}


Fildor's comment makes me realize that you actually never call the action.
public void RandomActions()
{
    var actions = new List<Action> { ... }; // Initialization as shown above
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int index = random.Next(actions.Count);

        // Execute the action:
        actions[index].Invoke(); // or simply: actions[index]();

        actions.RemoveAt(index);
    }
}


Tbh I am not to sure about those lambdas. Technically they work, but given the "use case" I would guess it could be a better idea to normalize to Action<DogsEnvironment> or something alike.

@Fildor, agree, but the string parameters (or no parameters) belong to different categories. So, I fear this might get too complex very fast.

"this might get too complex very fast." very much agreed.

I got rid of the errors using answer one. '''  The problem now is that the '''dog1.RandomActions(); dog2.RandomActions();''' don't write random methods to the console.

I tried option 2 with the lambda expression. I didn't get errors either but the RandomActions(); didn't do anything in the console.

In your example code, you don't seem to actually execute those actions? The methods just removes some from the local collection and that's it.

I got it to work! I decided to go with using a switch statement and a do while loop to randomly select and execute the code. This was my first post here so I don't know the etiquette so I apologize for any faux pas. Thanks Olivier Jacot-Descombes your help was encouraging.
    public void RandomlySelectAndExecute()
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int choice1 = random.Next(1, 13); // Generates a number between 1 and 12
    int choice2;

    do
    {
        choice2 = random.Next(1, 13); // Generates another number between 1 and 12
    } while (choice2 == choice1); // Ensure choice2 is different from choice1

    ExecuteChoice(choice1);
    ExecuteChoice(choice2);
}

public void ExecuteChoice(int choice)
{
    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Walk();
            break;
        case 2:
            Bark();
            break;
        case 3:
            Sleep();
            break;
        case 4:
            Eat();
            break;
        case 5:
            Play();
            break;
        case 6:
            Fetch();
            break;
        case 7:
            Dig();
            break;
        case 8:
            Swim();
            break;
        case 9:
            RollOver();
            break;
        case 10:
            Chase();
            break;
        case 11:
            Sniff();
            break;
        case 12:
            WagTail();
            break;
    }
}

}
